# How to optimize permissions on my front-end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a navbar and set of permissions coming from the backend I stored them inside user object in my global context, and I can reach them by typing`user.permissions`

```
{addCustomer: false, editAndDeleteCustomer: false, showAllCustomers: false, addEmployee: false, editAndDeleteEmployee: false, …}
```

How can I optimize my Navlinks by just displaying the True fields?

for example: if addCustomer is false, add customer shouldn't appear in menuItems and so on.

**here is my code:**

```
const NavLinks = ({ ToggleSideBar }) => {
  const { user } = useAppContext();

  const links = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "panel",

      path: "/",
      icon: <IoBarChartSharp />,
      menuItems: ["panel"],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "employee",
      // path: "all-jobs",
      path: ["add-employee", "all-employee"],
      icon: <MdQueryStats />,
      menuItems: [
        "add new employee",
        // "أدوار الموظفين",
        "all employees",
        // "الموظف المثالي",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "customer",
      // path: "add-job",
      path: ["add-customer", "emp-customers", "all-customers"],
      icon: <FaWpforms />,
      menuItems: [
        "add new customer",
        // "ارسال عميل",
        // "الحسابات المنتظرة",
        "my customers",
        "all customers",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      text: "التقارير",
      // path: 'profile',
      path: ["profile", "aw", "all-jobs", "add-job"],
      icon: <ImProfile />,
      menuItems: [
        "add customer",
        "customer Roles",
        "all customers",
        "الموظف المثالي",
      ],
    },
    
  ];
 
  const [isDropdownOpen2, setIsDropdownOpen2] = useState(false);
  const [isDropdownOpen3, setIsDropdownOpen3] = useState(false);

  const toggleDropdown2 = () => {
    setIsDropdownOpen2(!isDropdownOpen2);
  };
  const toggleDropdown3 = () => {
    setIsDropdownOpen3(!isDropdownOpen3);
  };

  const [activeStatus, setActiveStatus] = useState({
    firstnavcontainer: false,
    secondnavcontainer: false,
    thirdnavcontainer: false,
  });

  const firstFunction = () => {
    setActiveStatus((prevState) => ({
      firstnavcontainer: true,
      secondnavcontainer: false,
      thirdnavcontainer: false,
    }));
  };
  const secondFunction = () => {
    setActiveStatus((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      firstnavcontainer: false,
      secondnavcontainer: true,
      thirdnavcontainer: false,
    }));
    console.log(activeStatus);
  };
  const thirdFunction = () => {
    setActiveStatus((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      firstnavcontainer: false,
      secondnavcontainer: false,
      thirdnavcontainer: true,
    }));
  };
  return (
    <div className="nav-links">
      {links.map((link) => {
        const { text, path, id, icon, menuItems } = link;
        return (
          <>
            {/* first item */}
            {id === 1 && (
              <div className="nav-item extra" onClick={firstFunction}>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                  {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <NavLink
                      to={path[index]}
                      // onClick={ToggleSideBar}
                      className={({ isActive }) =>
                        isActive
                          ? "dropdownmenu-item red-background"
                          : "dropdownmenu-item"
                      }
                    >
                      <div className="dropdown-itemcontainer">
                        <span className="dropdown-itemtext">{item}</span>
                      </div>
                    </NavLink>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            )}
            {/* second section */}
            {id === 2 && (
              <div className="nav-item extra" onClick={secondFunction}>
                <button
                  className={`dropdown-toggle ${
                    activeStatus.secondnavcontainer ? "red-background" : ""
                  }`}
                >
                  <div className="dropdownbtn">
                    <span className="icon">{icon}</span>
                    <span>{text}</span>
                  </div>
                  <BsChevronDown
                    className="dropdown-icon"
                    onClick={toggleDropdown2}
                  />
                </button>
                {isDropdownOpen2 && (
                  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
                      <NavLink
                        to={path[index]}
                        // onClick={ToggleSideBar}
                        className={({ isActive }) =>
                          isActive
                            ? "dropdownmenu-item active"
                            : "dropdownmenu-item"
                        }
                      >
                        <div className="dropdown-itemcontainer">
                          <span className="dropdown-itemtext">{item}</span>
                        </div>
                      </NavLink>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
            {/* third section */}
            {id === 3 && (
              <div className="nav-item extra" onClick={thirdFunction}>
                <button
                  className={`dropdown-toggle ${
                    activeStatus.thirdnavcontainer ? "red-background" : ""
                  }`}
                >
                  <div className="dropdownbtn">
                    <span className="icon">{icon}</span>
                    <span>{text}</span>
                  </div>
                  <BsChevronDown
                    className="dropdown-icon"
                    onClick={toggleDropdown3}
                  />
                </button>
                {isDropdownOpen3 && (
                  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
                      <NavLink
                        to={path[index]}
                        // onClick={ToggleSideBar}
                        className={({ isActive }) =>
                          isActive
                            ? "dropdownmenu-item active"
                            : "dropdownmenu-item"
                        }
                      >
                        <div className="dropdown-itemcontainer">
                          <span className="dropdown-itemtext">{item}</span>
                        </div>
                      </NavLink>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </div>
            )}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavLinks;
```

Since It is a permissions-related problem, is there another approach to do this?

Comment: What correlates user permissions to any links that are being rendered? What exactly do you need to "optimize"?

Comment: i meant how can i change the structure of my navlinks , since add customer is false, add new customer in the menu item shouldn't appear in the interface in my navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a role/permission, or array of roles/permissions, field to the `links` array objects. These values should match a `user.permissions` object key.

Example:

```
const links = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "panel",
    path: "/",
    icon: <IoBarChartSharp />,
    menuItems: ["panel"],
    roles: null, // <-- any role/permission
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "employee",
    // path: "all-jobs",
    path: ["add-employee", "all-employee"],
    icon: <MdQueryStats />,
    menuItems: [
      "add new employee",
      // "أدوار الموظفين",
      "all employees",
      // "الموظف المثالي",
    ],
    roles: ["addEmployee"], // <-- only addEmployee role/permission
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "customer",
    // path: "add-job",
    path: ["add-customer", "emp-customers", "all-customers"],
    icon: <FaWpforms />,
    menuItems: [
      "add new customer",
      // "ارسال عميل",
      // "الحسابات المنتظرة",
      "my customers",
      "all customers",
    ],
    roles: ["addCustomer", "showAllCustomers"], // <-- addCustomer or showAllCustomers role/permission
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "التقارير",
    // path: 'profile',
    path: ["profile", "aw", "all-jobs", "add-job"],
    icon: <ImProfile />,
    menuItems: [
      "add customer",
      "customer Roles",
      "all customers",
      "الموظف المثالي",
    ],
    roles: ["showAllCustomers"], // <-- etc...
  },
];
```

Then filter the `links` array prior to mapping them.

```
{links
  .filter(link => link.roles?.length
    // if there are link roles to check, check them against the user permissions
    ? link.roles.some(role => user.permissions[role])
    // otherwise return true to include menu link item
    : true
  )
  .map((link) => {
    ...
  })
}
```

Comment: in case I want to show my customers which don't have any specific permissions is there any approach :))?

Comment: @MohammedM That's what the `link.roles?.length` check and ternary is for, if `roles` is falsey or an empty array the item should not be filtered out.